# Deploying Vaadin/SpringBoot as WAR

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, gradle, vaadin, vaadin8

Am trying to deploy a minimal Vaadin/SpringBoot application as a WAR file into a stand-alone Tomcat.

Everything works if I run `gradle vaadinRun` and access under `localhost:8080`, but creating the WAR file with `gradle war` and then copying it into the webapps folder of my Tomcat results in a 404. Unfortunately Tomcat logs don't show anything. Trying to access via `localhost:8080/hello-vaadin`.

Here is the application class itself:

```
package com.somecompany;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletComponentScan;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.EnableVaadin;

@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableVaadin
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        configureApplication(new SpringApplicationBuilder()).run(args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
         return configureApplication(builder);
    }

    private static SpringApplicationBuilder configureApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

This is the corresponding UI-class:

```
package com.somecompany;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.Grid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;

@SpringUI
@Theme("valo")
public class HelloWorldUI extends UI {

    @Autowired
    public HelloWorldUI() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        setContent(new Label("Hello World!"));
    }

}
```

And finally my gradle script:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "com.devsoap.plugin.vaadin" version "1.2.4"
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "1.5.7.RELEASE"
}

jar {
    baseName = 'com.somecompany.hello-vaadin'
    version =  '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'hello-vaadin'
    version =  '1.0'
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'com.somecompany.Application'
}

bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'com.somecompany.Application'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/" }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-release' }
    maven { url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
}
```

After going through tutorial after tutorial, there must be something that I overlook. But what, I don't see what the problem could be?

Any hints highly appreciated!

Comment: As maven user I need the spring-boot-maven-plugin, maybe there is an equivalent for gradle too?

Comment: @Jay Yes, I can see the app from the manager page.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic That should be done with in the 4th line, the org.springframework.boot plugin.

Comment: You should definetly ramp up the logging on your tomcat to see either the error, why it did not deploy or see what actually happened and where that war shows up now.  Everything else is just guesswork.

Comment: @cfrick The WAR file gets deployed correctly, will be unpacked, shows up in the tomcat manager. But request returns 404. I would be happier with a 50x and something useful in the logs, but a 404 is a 404 ...

Comment: But you should see log output from your springboot application (which e.g. prints the url with context).  If there is nothing you could as well deploy an empty war.  Has the war resonable content and size? E.g. is it similar to the content of the fatjar springboot creates?

Comment: Also what is the exact name of the war that you're deploying?

Comment: The war file is just fine, it has all the contents it needs and the correct name. The problem is with the code. Have figured it out and will post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I have managed to make it work. This is how:

MyApplication.java

```
package com.somecompany;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

MyServletInitializer.java

```
package com.somecompany;

import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

public class MyServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }
}
```

MyConfiguration.java

```
package com.somecompany;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public String myLabelString() {
        return "Hello World Bean!";
    }
}
```

HelloWorldUI.java

```
package com.somecompany;

import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;

@SpringUI
public class HelloWorldUI extends UI {

    @Autowired
    String helloWorldString;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        if (helloWorldString != null) {
            setContent(new Label(helloWorldString));
        } else {
            setContent(new Label("Injection does not work!"));
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.devsoap.plugin.vaadin' version '1.2.1'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.3.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'hellovaadin'
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'com.somecompany.MyApplication'
}
```

Then with `gradle build` I build the WAR file and then copy it into the `webapps` folder of my tomcat instance.

I have extended the example by also showing how to inject/autowire a bean.

Comment: You could even improve your code by using constructor injection iso field injection.